# $2 \to 2$ scattering cross section in arbitrary theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams, interactions, scattering-cross-section

What is the general method to compute the $2 \to 2$ scattering cross section given an arbitrary Lagrangian ? I would like a step by step recipe that can be easily implemented in Mathematica.

For example, I want to input one of these Lagrangians

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2-\frac{g}{4!}\phi^4$

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2-\frac{g}{3!}\phi^3$

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi+ g(\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi)^2 $

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi + g(\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi)\phi^2 $

and have outputted the $2 \to 2$ cross section to the first non trivial order in $g$.

I think I understand how to compute the cross section for the two first lagrangians:

- write the $M$ matrix elements enumerating the Feynman diagrams and using momentum Feynman rules (Schwartz box 7.1)
- use the formula for $2\to 2$ scattering $\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=\frac{1}{60\pi^2E_{cm}^2}|M|^2$ (Schwartz 5.33)

but it seems like this method would only work for a lagrangian of the form $\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2-\frac{g}{n!}\phi^n$.

Hence, the 2 remaining questions are: How to deal with the two last lagrangians ? How to automatically enumerate the Feynman diagrams ?

Comment: Have you tried to look into this? There are a lot of textbooks that outline this theory, Peskin and Schroeder is one such reference. Free copies of this textbook are available online. If you need help understanding the derivation definitely edit your question and we can help.

Comment: What do you already know about cross section formulas?

Comment: I'm reading Schwartz. I just edited the question adding what I already know.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9812357) might possibly help